# What does "offstage cyclone" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, definition

The situation is this. A theatrical actress asks her producer to give her daughter a small part in one of the next shows. Here's the dialogue:

- Can't we find her a small part next season?
- If Nancy's doing it, it won't be a small part.
- Oh, well, there must be something.
- Maybe I'll look for a nice **offstage cyclone** for her to do.

It's surely some kinda joke, but I don't understand it completely. Could offstage cyclone mean some kind of theatrical noises of storm during a show or something? Like wanted sounds for a show's sound decoration?

Answer (score 3):

"Offstage cyclone" is not an idiom or recognised phrase. It has no meaning outside of a particular narrative like this.

The speaker is implying that they will not give the daughter a part on stage, but is joking that if they need a very violent disturbance offstage, they'll consider the daughter. This seems to imply that the producer regards Nancy as noisy, violent, or disruptive.